# Javascript: use loop variable values as keys of objects

Tags: javascript, object

Let us simplify my issue; I have this piece of code:

```js
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  arr.push({
    i: i + 1
  })
}
console.log(arr)
```

This outputs: `Array [Object { i: 1 }, Object { i: 2 }]`
But I want : `Array [Object { 0: 1 }, Object { 1: 2 }] // Values of 'i' as object keys`

How to achieve this?

Comment: `arr.push({[i]: i + 1})`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and take a single loop with an object with a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
var array = Array.from({ length: 2 }, (_, i) => ({ [i]: i + 1 }));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use ES6 then this should work.

```js
let arr = []
for(let i=0; i<2; i++) {
  arr.push({
    [i]: i+1
  })
}
console.log(arr)
```